# Re-using a list in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

I'm developing a web scraper in Node JS and I'm trying to figure out the best approach to combine data from one list, with data on another list.

For example:

**Step 1: Scrape data from website A**

In this step, I scrape some data using cheerio/request and store this in a list, which is then  displayed on the screen in a jQuery data table. The data table has a checkbox next to each scraped row of data and the value I have assigned to each checkbox is a "URL".

**Step 2: Scrape again based on URLs chosen in checkboxes**

In step 2, the app will scrape another website based on the URLs selected in step 1 and will retrieve some data values from these URLs that are scraped.

**My dilemma**

I wish to use some data values that were scraped in step 1 along with some data values scraped in step 2. However currently in my app, the data from Step 1 has been lost because it's not being saved anywhere.

Since this is a sort of dynamic search whereby a user will search for data, scrape it and then not neccessarily want to see it again, I think saving data into a database would be overkill? So I'm wondering if I should save the list data from step 1 into a session variable and then link them up together again using the URL (in the checkbox) as the key?

Thanks for your help!

Anthony

Comment: @EaterOfCode - I haven't tried anything yet. I'll be trying tonight after work. I wanted to see if I was approaching this the right way before going down any particular route (still very new to Node.JS). Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure I understand. How is it lost? You scrap the site, parse it. Draw a list (JavaScript array) then promptly garbage collect the array? That is a big code smell if that were true. Save a reference to the array with a variable that is in scope or accessible to the next scraping function.

Comment: Show some code. JSBin.com or JSFiddle.net or gist.github.com

Comment: Hi @Sukima - what I mean by lost, is that when you go to another page/step, the data from the previous step is not available unless you save it to a session or database? I have seen res.locals but that's for use in the current request only right? So to use a variable in another page completely, I thought you have to use sessions or database to save the data first, so it can be re-used, hence my question.

Comment: @Sukima, I will put together some code examples now.

Comment: Here is the code on JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/45u8R/

Is that enough to have an idea of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: There's localStorage for small data client side. Then there are DB services like CouchDB, Redis, etc. server side. Or an API server you write yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to do saving for these data then pass it as another inputs of your form ,  try

```
< input type=hidden value=json.stringify(item)/>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me and was the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think using database for storage of the scrapped conetent would be an overkill.

The ideal points to note in this process would be.

1. Use a document store like mongoDB to dump your json data directly. I proposed mongoDB because you get more resources to refer.
2. Initially open up a db connection in node and your scraping deamon can reuse it for each time  when it parses the http result using cheerio and dumps it to db.
3. Here Once you get the output from http request to your Target URL, the cheerio parse steps should take more time than dumping the data to a db.

I have followed a similar approach for scrapping movie data from imdb and you can find the corresponding code in [**this repo**](https://github.com/mithunsatheesh/imdb-scrapper), if you are interested. I have also used cheerio and its a good selection in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @mithunsatheesh - I am currently using MongoDB for my user data so this could be feasible, however my hosting provider only gives me 500MB to play with - if I do use the database route, what would be the best way to flush the data when the user has finished searching? 

Would you delete the data for the logged in user when the user first accesses the search page in Step 1? Or another way? 

Thanks

Comment: Ok in your case you can use a cache solution like redis and set the data with a ttl i guess. So once the Time To Live expires your space will be freed up.